# Access root domain's localStorage from subdomain

Tags: javascript, local-storage, subdomain

### EDIT:

For the sake of simplicity:

I've got a simple UserJS script (FF/Chrome: Greasemonkey, Opera: built-in) that fixes some issues on website I'm using quite often. The problem is that I need to store some data between different requests. My first attempt was `LocalStorage` but it fail when it came to work with subdomains: `www.domain.com` and `subdomain.domain.com` (unfortunately root-domain is subdomain in fact - stupid `www`) . I need to be able to access some data source that would be available everywhere.

Now I'm stuck - any ideas?

Comment: could you put the common data in LocalStorage under 'domain.com'?

Comment: As I said that's UserJS script so I'm not able to do such things.

Comment: See also: **[how to access a subdomain's html5 localStorage from the root domain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343645)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

...Why not use [GM_setValue](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_setValue) and [GM_getValue](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_getValue)?

**EDIT:** I did a little digging. Look what I found!

http://www.opera.com/docs/userjs/specs/#scriptstorage

It claims to work the same as localStorage, but it's scoped per-script, rather than per-website. Should work perfect for your use case.

Comment: Unfortunately Opera doesn't provide anything like this as far as I know.

Comment: Then you're almost certainly out of luck. Firefox and Chrome both support ways for user scripts to persist data. Have you tried globalStorage? Does that work in Opera?

Comment: I just had an idea: use cookies. The downside is, the server will see the cookie data as well, and cookies are a pain to work with.

Comment: Don't use either globalStorage or cookies. I edited my answer to show the solution for Opera.

Comment: I'll test that tomorrow, however it seems to be just what I am looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You can not.

For security reasons the browser only grants access to data stored with localStorage within the same domain. This is due to the fact, that on some systems different subdomains belong to different people / websites.

See for example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197062(VS.85).aspx

> Each domain and subdomain has its own
>   separate local storage area. Domains
>   can access the storage areas of
>   subdomains, and subdomains can access
>   the storage areas of parent domains.
>   For example,
>   localStorage['example.com'] is
>   accessible to example.com and any of
>   its subdomains. The subdomain
>   localStorage['www.example.com'] is
>   accessible to example.com, but not to
>   other subdomains, such as
>   mail.example.com.

Comment: Uh...does't that quote boil down to 'you should be able to'?

Comment: `and subdomains can access the storage areas of parent domains` that's what I am looking for. But `localStorage['...']` - that's not proper way.

Comment: I tried localStorage['example.com'] and could not get it to work.  Tried it in 3 different browser/OS combos: Firefox, IE8, Chrome.  P.S. document.domain appears to be the entire FQDN hostname.