# Local Storage under Sub-domain

Tags: local-storage

I am writing a user script which use Local Storage to save users' setting.
As local storage is unique for each domain, how can I share the Local Storage between example.com and www.example.com?

Comment: See also: **[how to access a subdomain's html5 localStorage from the root domain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343645)** and **[Access root domain's localStorage from subdomain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414809)**

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to avoid the problem - just **don't use both** non-www and www domain names at once, you should choose one and do **permanent redirect** from second one. The reasons for this are not only connected with local storage, the main issue here is search engine optimisation.